# How to show only 'Open in source Panel' option when right click from Developers Tools using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

In a Browser when we open websites and open Developrs toos and right click on .Css
or .Js file then there is four option will be shown. example like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t50ik.jpg)

But i want to show only 'Open in source Panel' option when right click from Developers Tools, want to disable other option, example like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aPso.jpg)

So, May i know how it will be possible by javascirpt, jquery ??

Comment: `developer tools` provided by browser not by code so  you cant change the settings using `javascript` `jquery`

Comment: so i have to change setting from all browsers ?? check one Demo example 
http://www.wethemez.com/demo/primary/all-template/index.html